# Run shell script with Oozie: how to get the script path in HDFS inside the script

Tags: shell, hdfs, oozie

I am running a Shell script with Oozie. First I uploaded the script to HDFS, then script should forward its logs to a log file in the same directory where this script is stored in HDFS, meaning the generated log file should be in the HDFS.

Anyone knows how to achieve this goal?

Comment: It is simple to define the HDFS directory of the script as a parameter in workflow.xml and then this parameter value is passed to the script, but this step seems to be unnecessary, there might be some shortcut for this. Anyone knows?

Comment: How were you able to achieve this in HDFS. I am able to do this in Linux but not in HDFS

Answer (score 0):

> ...a log file in the same directory where this script is stored in HDFS...

The Oozie Shell action contains a `<file>` element with the HDFS path of the script. But the way it works is not what you seem to think:

1. Oozie aks YARN to allocate a container somewhere
2. Oozie asks YARN to **download** some files to the container's **private local filesystem** (in CWD), and especially the `<file>` stuff
3. finally, Oozie asks YARN to run the
   **local** version of the script

Bottom line: the script that is executed has no way to know its original HDFS directory. The Action must pass that directory *explicitly* as a script argument, or as an env variable.

Assuming that you use an env variable, the obvious solution to run the archive part is something like
`hdfs dfs -appendToFile ./MySession.log $LOG_ARCHIVE_DIR/archive.log`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation :) I indeed solved this problem with environment variable